# universal link doesn't work when user change default browser

Tags: ios, google-chrome, ios-universal-links

after iOS 17.4 users can modify the default browser from safari to any other browsers that they installed on their iPhone, and the problem is when the user changes the default browser from Safari to something else ( it doesn't matter if Chrome or Firefox or etc), universal links don't work.

does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: This isn't new with iOS 17.4. Users have been able to select a different browser as a default for some time. Universal links do not work when an alternate browser is set as the default. The only work around is to provide a link on the web page that the user ends up at that can open your app via a url scheme.